# mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in Inicio de sesión

Tags: mysql, mysqli

soy nuevo en esto de MySQL y PHP.

Tengo un codigo que es de inicio de sesión algo viejo que usa mysql_query(), sin embargo si lo pongo como mysqli_query() me da el siguiente error:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/path/index.php on line 26

Las lineas que dan el error son estas:

```
$query =mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)

    {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
```

Que podré hacer para corregirlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He dado con la solución con ayuda de otro post en Inglés.

Me faltaba un dato "$con", el código queda así

```
$query =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
```